# ES bulk indexing shows few documents deleted

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I indexed 443663 documents in ES.
When I do GET /_stats it shows

```
"primaries":{
"docs:{
"count": 443625,
"deleted":38
}
}
}
```

Interesting thing is sum of count+deleted = 443663
Weird thing is  why did it deleted those?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Do you have "delete" commands in your bulk or only "index" commands?

Comment: just "index" commands

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your bulk call, you have 38 duplicate ids, i.e. 38 commands for a document that has a same id as another one that has already been indexed.

It's easy to reproduce:

```
POST test2/_doc/_bulk
{"index": {"_id": 1}}
{"test": 1}
{"index": {"_id": 1}}
{"test": 1}
{"index": {"_id": 2}}
{"test": 1}
{"index": {"_id": 3}}
{"test": 1}
```

Now `GET test2/_stats` produces this because document with id `1` was indexed twice:

```
"primaries" : {
  "docs" : {
    "count" : 3,
    "deleted" : 1
  },
```